# Plotting Open and Closed Dots for Endpoints

Tags: plotting

In traditional textbooks you'll see open and closed dots to indicate whether to include or exclude the point respectively.  How can I modify this code to include open and closed dots at x=2?  I don't see any options available in `Plot`.

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{.5 (x - 2)^2 + 4, x < 2}, {1, x >= 2}}], {x, -2, 5}]
```

I'm looking for something like below. I'm hoping to avoid manually adding dots using `Graphics` `Point` and then specify the exact coordinates.  This is a pain. Is there a faster way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{.5 (x - 2)^2 + 4, x < 2}, {1, x >= 2}}], {x, -2, 5},
 Epilog -> {
   PointSize[0.03], Blue, Point[{2, 1}],
   PointSize[0.02], White, Point[{2, 1}],
   PointSize[0.03], Blue, Point[{2, 4}]},
 Exclusions -> 2,
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]